# Magento 2 - Order Item changes

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-order, invoice

I want to inform customers with email all the details of their orders and I want to be able to show the difference. For example:

```
Those items shipped: ...
Those items cancelled: ...
Those items ...
```

`credit memo, hold, invoice, ship, reorder, create returns...` There so many situations. What should be the best way to achieve this?

Still I tried to use events for invoices (`sales_order_invoice_save_after` - `sales_order_invoice_register`):

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $stateProcessing = $order::STATE_PROCESSING;

    $collection = $order->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $this->logger->info('item = '.$item->getName());
        $this->logger->info('   qty_invoiced = '.$item->getData('qty_invoiced'));
        $this->logger->info('   qty_invoicedorig = '.$item->getOrigData('qty_invoiced'));
    }

    return $this;
}
```

But quantities are the same, couldn't get the difference.

Comment: Did you want only invoiced?

Comment: No, i want every actions. shipment, returns etc..

Comment: yes invoice and order item data are same if you try to create a partial credit memo for that then get it actually different in data.

Comment: Hmm I will try this. But what about shipments? Which event should I use for shipments

Comment: I have posted an answer please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the event list used to get the order collections data.

```
 - sales_order_save_after
 - sales_order_invoice_save_after
 - sales_order_shipment_save_after
 - sales_order_creditmemo_save_after
```